# Encapsulating ublas and overloading the const reference to the operator()

Tags: c++, boost-ublas

Considering the following toy example, where I declare a class which encapsulates `ublas` from **boost libraries**:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_sparse.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas;

class UblasEncapsulated {
public:
    ublas::compressed_matrix<float>::reference operator()(int i, int j){
        std::cout << "Non const reference" << std::endl;
        MtrUpdated_ = true;
        return mtr_(i, j);
    }

    ublas::compressed_matrix<float>::const_reference operator()(
        int i, int j) const {
        std::cout << "Const reference" << std::endl;
        return mtr_(i, j);
    }

    UblasEncapsulated() { MtrUpdated = false; }

private:
    ublas::compressed_matrix<float> mtr_(3, 3);
    bool MtrUpdated_;
};

int main() {
    UblasEncapsulated foo;

    foo(2, 0) =  1.0f;
    float const foo_float = foo(2, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the output

```
Non constant reference
Constant reference
```

But I got

```
Non constant reference
Non constant reference
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I properly track when `mtr_` could have its values changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` is non-const, so the non-const version of `foo.operator()` will be called.  It doesn't matter how the value it returns is used.

If you really want to know that `MtrUpdated_` is only set true if an element is actually assigned to, you will need to use a proxy class:

```
class UblasEncapsulated {
public:
    class proxy {
    public:
        proxy(UblasEncapsulated* ptr, int i, int j)
            : ptr_(ptr), i_(i), j_(j)
        {}

        proxy& operator=(float f) {
            ptr_->MtrUpdated_ = true;
            ptr_->mtr_(i_, j_) = f;
            return *this;
        }

        operator float() {
            return ptr_->mtr_(i_, j_);
        }

    private:
        UblasEncapsulated* ptr_;
        int i_;
        int j_;
    };      

    proxy operator()(int i, int j) {
        return proxy(this, i, j);
    }

    ublas::compressed_matrix<float>::const_reference operator() (int i, int j) const {
        return mtr_(i, j);
    }

    UblasEncapsulated()
        : mtr_(3, 3),
          MtrUpdated_(false)
    {}

private:
    ublas::compressed_matrix<float> mtr_;
    bool MtrUpdated_;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/200d8fb9e9e885b3)

Note that you should avoid using a proxy class if you can get away with it since it doesn't play nicely with things like `auto` or template argument deduction.

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks!